# Unable to style selected date in kendo-datepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I'm unable to change the background color of selected date in kendo-datepicker. This is how it looks, I want the entire blue box to be red.

[image]

This is how I'm selecting the element,

```
.k-calendar .k-state-selected {
background-color: red;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I applied color to the k-state-selected class and it added the color like it should can you share your code stackblitz you might have conflicting classes

Answer (score 1):

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendoui-datepicker-kwsdqd?file=styles.css,app%2Fapp.component.ts)
this demo is a forked stackblitz of kendo-datepicker with k-state-selected class in styles.css

```css
.k-state-selected {
  background: red !important;
  color:white !important
}
```